# symbol to use for minus `1 month` in `dayTimeDuration` from `dateTime`

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Anyone knows what symbol to use for minus `1 month` in `dayTimeDuration` from `dateTime`?

`xs:dayTimeDuration('-P30D')` subtracts 30 days which could indirectly be a month. But, in the cases where feb has 28 days, will this still be accurate?

http://www.datypic.com/sc/xsd/t-xsd_dayTimeDuration.html

Comment: `fn:current-dateTime() + xs:yearMonthDuration('-P1M')`, is there any way I can format this to `"yyyy:MM:dd HH:mm:ss"` using xpath?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the name implies, `xs:dayTimeDuration` can only contain days, hours, minutes, and seconds. If you need a duration with months, you either have to use `xs:duration` or `xs:yearMonthDuration`. Minus 1 month would be

```
xs:duration('-P1M')
```

or

```
xs:yearMonthDuration('-P1M')
```

Comment: However, subtracting a month from a dateTime is somewhat subjective. What do you want 31 March minus one month to be?